# How can I mask the URL path to a webpage within my website?

Tags: url, html, mask

I have a website with a default home page of index.html, let's call the website: www.brianbauer.com ( that is my name BTW).

www.brianbauer.com operates something like a "treasure hunt".  by clicking on various hot-spots on each HTML page access via brianbauer.com, you get redirected to the next html page.  this continues for some period of user-clicks.  One of the ideas is that on each visit, it is not obvious how the user reached a specific webpage.  all they know is that they kept clicking and ended up at some final HTML page.  but every click that brings up a new HTML page, still shows "http://www.brianbauer.com" in the Address bar.  This is a game, nothing "wrong" going on here.
1.  All of the HTML pages are owned by me, and I authored them all.
2.  No illegal or unscruptulous activty of any kind going on.
3.  all HTML pages in scope are under the root domain of brianbauer.com

the idea is that as users look at pictures and read a narrative, they make choices.  a typical webpage might have 4 choices.  depending on your choice, the next HTML page you see is determined.
I have created site maps that are basically decision trees.
think of it like a digital corn-maze.  It's important that the full URL path to the current HTML page that they are looking at is masked, and should only show "www.brianbauer.com".  it is true that someone more sophisticated could look at sourcecode, record their screen, keep notes, etc.  but the mask will accomplish 90% of my goal.

as for being able to bookmark a certain webpage that they have "discovered"?  the whole point is that they should not be able to....

I am NOT trying to mask my domain, that is easy.  I am trying to simply maske what appears in the Address bar as users hit HTML pages which are children of that domain.

Thank you for the help.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

There is something called CNAME cloak it might be one option.
Another option could be using ajax and replace content of the page.